# How to update the string name of an item inside a DefaultListModel

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have a `Jlist` with a `DefaultListModel` with data from XML.

I want to be able change the name of the item in the `Jlist`. but the `DefaultListModel` has no update method.

So if the user clicks on a name it should edit the name.

So far I thought if I get the location of the item and remove it and update with new data. But if I update with then new name will it be put in the same location as the old or will things be messed up ?

My code :

```
private class EditName extends AbstractAction {
        public EditName() {
            putValue(NAME, "Change Name");
            putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Some short description");
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

             int x = objTypeJList.getSelectedIndex();
               String newName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("New Name?");

                 if (x >= 0) {
                   String oldName = ReadXMLFile.getInstance().getModel().getElementAt(x).toString();
                   ReadXMLFile.getInstance().getModel().removeElementAt(x);
                   objTypeJList.setModel(ReadXMLFile.getInstance().getModel());
                }
                    // newText I wanna add into the the location I edit
            }

    }
```

Comment: `But if I update with then new name will it be put in the same location as the old or will things be messed up ?` Try it and let us know what happens. You learn by trying things. Why does your code remove one element but then update the entire model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "I want to be able change the name of the item in the Jlist. but the **`DefaultListModel` has no update method**."

What makes you say that? Have you looked carefully at the [**docs**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) ?

What do you think this method does?

- [`public void setElementAt(E element, int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#setElementAt%28E,%20int%29) - Sets the component at the specified index of this list to be the specified element. **The previous component at that position is discarded.**

OR

- [`public E set(int index, E element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#set%28int,%20E%29) - **Replaces the element at the specified position** in this list with the specified element.

Comment: Right thats correct. Lol I only read the method names.